# Haskell: Problems with overloading: Interpreter can´t tell which + to use

Tags: haskell, overloading

I want to make functions Double -> Double an instance of the Num typeclass.
I want to define the sum of two functions as sum of their images.
So I wrote

```
instance Num Function where

f + g = (\ x -> (f x) + (g x))
```

Here the compiler complains he can´t tell whether I´m using Prelude.+ or Module.+
in the lambda expression.
So I imported Prelude qualified as P and wrote

```
instance Num Function where

f + g = (\ x -> (f x) P.+ (g x))
```

This compiles just fine, but when I try to add two functions in GHCi
the interpreter complains again he can´t tell whether I´m using `Prelude.+` or
`Module.+`.
Is there any way I can solve this problem?

Comment: By the way, I believe it's considered good form on SO to mark an answer as accepted if it solved your problem--it's not a big deal to me personally, but it may discourage other people from posting answers in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler is complaining because you're defining a *new* function named `+`, rather than defining an implementation of `+` for a class instance. Are you forgetting to indent the function definition? You want something like this:

```
instance Num (Double -> Double) where
    f + g = (\ x -> (f x) + (g x))
```

Not like this:

```
instance Num (Double -> Double) where

f + g = (\ x -> (f x) + (g x))
```

That said, a `Num` instance for a function type isn't really going to work properly for various reasons, most significantly that `Num` instances are required to also be instances of `Eq` and `Show`, neither of which can really be defined on functions in a way that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, I really forgot the indentation!
Thank you very much!
Now everything works fine. :)

Comment: Actually I made an algebraic datatype Function, which derives Eq and Show. I just wanted to make my posting short, so I thought I skip
the unnecessary details.
Thanks again, and sorry I forgot to mark your answer as accepted.
I´m new to this.

Comment: @Ben: Okay, that does sound more reasonable. And no worries about not knowing to accept--we're all here to learn.